# Escaping new line character in CSON

Tags: special-characters, atom-editor, code-snippets

So when I use Atom text editor I often use `Snippets`. They are writen in `.cson` files like this:

```
'.source.cpp':
  'cout':
    'prefix': 'cout'
    'body': 'std::cout << "${1:/* message */}" << \n;$2'
```

Now, when I write it like this, Atom interprets `\n` as a new line character and instead of:

`std::cout << "${1:/* message */}" << \n`

I get:

```
std::cout << "${1:/* message */}" <<
```

(with new line automatically inserted)

How can I make it to treat `\n` just as a string of text?

Comment: Try escaping the `\ ` character: `'body': 'std::cout << "${1:/* message */}" << \\n;$2'` (notice the double `\\ `)

Comment: Then it goes for: `std::cout << "/* message */" << n;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 4 backslashes to make this work.

```coffeescript
'.source.cpp':
  'cout':
    'prefix': 'cout'
    'body': 'std::cout << "${1:/* message */}" << \\\\n;$2'
```

This expands in editor to:

```cpp
std::cout << "/* message */" << \n;
```

I'm not familiar enough with Atom's internals to explain this fully, but it may be that it interpolates things once when it loads the cson file (resulting in `\\n`) and then again during the insert (resulting in the final output string `\n`).

Answer (score 0):

To properly escape `\n` you will have to use `\\n` in a single-line string. However, take note that CSON also supports multi-line strings, which is often better to maintain.

**Example:**

```
body: """
  std::cout << "${1:/* message */}" <<
  $0
"""
```

The `$0` tab-stop always comes last, but there's nothing wrong with `$2`.

Comment: The OP did not want an actual newline, they wanted to insert the two-character sequence `\n`.